# How to output only one value of an array within an array of a state in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Say I want to console.log the name value in the following state in React:

```
state = {
   editingToggle: false,
   list : [
      {id:1 name:'hello' address: '123 fake street'},
   ]
}
```

How would I be able to access only this value? I've tried console.log(this.state.list[1].name) console.log(this.state.list.name[1])  but to no avail.

Whenever I open up the browser console all I can see is undefined. Any help would be great

Comment: Please provide more related code, by now it's hard to tell where went wrong

Comment: js arrays are zero based. so `this.state.list[0].name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript do not start with one, they start with zero. It's known as "Zero base numbering" or "Zero base indexing" which means, the first index of an array should be accessed with `0`, not `1`.

```
state = {
   editingToggle: false,
   list : [
      {id:1 name:'hello' address: '123 fake street'},
   ]
}

console.log(this.state.list[0]); // {id:1 name:'hello' address: '123 fake street'
console.log(this.state.list[0].name); // 'hello'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!